# How to get list of region programmatically in Window Azure

Tags: azure

One query about window azure that **is there any way to get programmatic list of Regions  which we are choosing while hosting our app?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I can think of is to use the [REST Management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx).

You have to query the Management API, and call the [List Locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg441293.aspx) method. You will however need a management certificate and a subscription id to do so. You can have the result cached for some time, if you are doing it very ofetn. I think that 1 hour is fair enough time to keep the locations cached. I don't expect that a change would happen that often, but it's good to refresh your list of locations from time to time.

[Here is one example](http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/02/leveraging-the-windows-azure-service-management-rest-api-to-create-your-hosted-service-namespace/) you can use. And [here is a NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement.Library) that wraps everything around, so you don't need to construct your REST calls manually.

Comment: Hi, The example link you've posted is no longer valid. Do you have another or maybe a code snippet that could replace it? Thanks

Answer (score 16):

CLI

```
az account list-locations
```

Powershell

```
Get-AzLocation
```

Comment: Thanks! `az account list-locations` is exactly what I needed!

Comment: In the new Az Powershell, it's now Get-AzLocation. https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Az.Resources/Get-AzLocation